# Spring Cloud Gateway Redis Rate Limiting Database Entries

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have implemented an API gateway with Spring cloud gateway. I have added the Redis rate limiters with below configurations:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
    routes:
    - id: user-service
      uri: lb://user-service
      predicates:
      - Path=/user/**
      filters:
      - StripPrefix=1
      - name: RequestRateLimiter
        args:
          key-resolver: "#{@remoteAddrKeyResolver}"
          redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate: 1
          redis-rate-limiter.burstCapacity: 5
---
spring:
  redis:
    host: localhost
    port: 6379
    database: 0
```

I can successfully block the user requests with an error code 429 TOO Many requests.

Now, I want the same entry to be inserted into the Redis database so that I can analyze.

What configuration do I need to make?
I have visited a blog where he shows it but I couldn't find code related to it. Here is the [a link](https://www.cnblogs.com/xiaobin-hlj80/p/10078638.html/) to that blog.

Also, Can anyone explain the exact **difference between replenishRate vs burstCapacity** with some example? I am a bit confused here.

Comment: There's not a way to add the 429 to a database. We have an open issue to use an exception which you could then respond to. We use the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket algorithm. Replenish rate is the rate tokens are added to the bucket. Burst capacity is the number of tokens the bucket can hold.

Comment: @spencergibb thanks for the reply. Is there any way we can track the number of users exceeding the replenish rate along with some basis users data?

Comment: There is not a way to do that currently

Comment: @spencergibb Can you explain how the rate limiting mechanism is working internally with Redis DB as I don't see any entries related to it in my local Redis DB. Also, can you tell me how can I use this in a clustered environment? I have two instances of API gateway in my application.

Comment: They keys time out, so unless you have constant traffic, there may be nothing there when you go to look. Clustering of gateways should have no effect, in fact, the reason to use redis is BECAUSE of clustering.

Comment: @spencergibb I have written some controllers in the API gateway which I access from my other microservices through feign client in which I have two questions : 
1) Is there any way I can restrict the traffic coming from outside and only allow traffic from my microservices.
2) When I write a controller in the API gateway, it is directly accessing the endpoints without going to the filters (redis rate limiter & custom filter) I have written in the gateway routes in my bootstrap.yml file. Is there any way I can validate them as well?

Comment: Using `uri: forward:/mycontroller`, yes you can.